# Query to get soft deleted records in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, querydsl

I have written an Hibernate query to soft delete some rows which means I am setting the columns active = 0 and deleted = 1.(Two distinct columns for soft deletion operation).

- If active=1 and delete=0, then only I can access that row.
- But If active=0 and delete=1 , then I cannot access that row.

Can I override the QueryDsl Executor provider to access soft deleted rows ?